# Clear localStorage on every refresh in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router-guards

I am storing a token in localStorage after authentication, but i need to delete it and redirect to some router each time i do a refresh.

I have no ideea how to do it in angular. I am using a very hacky way using plain js.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
  if (window.sessionStorage !== null && (window.location.href.indexOf('/signin') === -1 &&  window.location.href.indexOf('confirm-user') === -1)) {
    window.sessionStorage.clear();
    window.location.href = '/signin';
  }
});
```

I was thinking of adding an authentication guard, but i'm sure there should be a more angular way of doing this.

Comment: If you have a value that you don’t want to survive a page reload (assuming that’s what you mean by “doing a refresh”) - then why do you put it into localstorage in the first place …? A plain old normal JavaScript _variable_ would achieve that without you having to perform any extra steps ...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create some auth service to store your token as a plain variable and a [Guard](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards) to prevent redirects to secured pages without token. You can implement it in one service:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {
    token:String;
    canActivateChild = this.canActivate;
    constructor(private router: Router) {}
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        if (!this.token) {
            this.router.navigate(['/signin']);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

export const ROUTES: Routes = [{
    path: 'signup',
    component: SignupComponent
}, {
    path: 'securedpath',
    component: SecuredComponent,
    canActivateChild: [AuthService],
    canActivate: [AuthService]
}]
```

But this service should be singleton. Keep it in mind. Declare it in providers list of your app.module (or core.module if your using Jonh Papa's styleguide)